# MySQL compound index not used (intersection)

Tags: mysql

I'm running a search on user_profile table, containing individual indexes as well as compound index:

```
    SELECT ••• 
      FROM user_profile up
      JOIN auth_user au
        ON au.id = up.user_id 
      LEFT 
      JOIN _basecountry bc
        ON bc.id = up.country_id = 
      LEFT 
      JOIN _relationshipstatus rs
        ON rs.id = up.relationship_status_id 
      LEFT 
      JOIN _workstatus ws
        ON ws.id = up.work_status_id
      LEFT 
      JOIN _fieldofwork fw
        ON fw.id = up.field_of_work_id 
      LEFT 
      JOIN _fieldofstudy fs
        ON fs.id = up.field_of_study_id 
      LEFT 
      JOIN _educationlevel el
        ON el.id = up.education_level_id 
      LEFT 
      JOIN _religion r
        ON r.id = up.religion_id 
     WHERE up.lazy = 0 
       AND up.has_avatar = 1 
       AND up.inactive = 1 
       AND up.id <> 3247028 
       AND up.city = 'London' 
       AND up.challenge_count < 10 
       AND up.age BETWEEN 18 AND 28 
       AND up.gender = 'F' 
       AND up.id > 1468899 
     LIMIT 25
```

Explain results are:

> POSSIBLE_KEYS PRIMARY,user_id,compound_match,age,gender,challenge_count,lazy,city,has_avatar,inactive
>
> KEY    city,lazy,has_avatar
>
> KEY_LEN    578,1,1    None
>
> ROWS   1224
>
> EXTRA Using intersect(city,lazy,has_avatar); Using where

Compound index 'compound_match' combines used columns: id,user_id,age,gender,challenge_count,lazy,has_avatar,inactive

why mysql prefer intersect over it? As a result the query is slow.

Comment: Query reformatted for clarity. Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is largely meaningless. And your explain appears incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of columns in an index matters. You should create an index with the following rules in mind (assuming all search terms are combined with `AND`):

1. Columns referenced in **equality** conditions go first. The order of these doesn't matter much, but I prefer to list them from most selective to least.
2. Next is either *one* column referenced in a **range** condition, or else one or more columns by which you are sorting or grouping. If you have multiple range conditions (as you do in this query), sorry, you can expect only one of the columns to benefit from an index. So pick the column that is most selective (i.e. helps to narrow down the search by the best ratio).
3. Additional columns by which you are neither searching nor sorting, but you want to fetch as part of an **index-only query**. But remember the maximum number of columns in a MySQL index is 16.

So in this case, you have the following conditions on the user_profile table:

- up.lazy = 0 (equality)
- up.has_avatar = 1 (equality)
- up.inactive = 1 (equality)
- up.id <> 3247028 (range)
- up.city = 'London' (equality)
- up.challenge_count < 10 (range)
- up.age BETWEEN 18 AND 28 (range)
- up.gender = 'F' (equality)
- up.id > 1468899 (range)

You have no sorting going on (though as @Strawberry points out, perhaps you should, if you use LIMIT).

You have other columns that are not being used for searching, but are referenced in join conditions:

- up.user_id
- up.country_id
- up.relationship_status_id
- up.work_status_id
- up.field_of_work_id
- up.field_of_study_id
- up.education_level_id
- up.religion_id

So I would create the index with columns in the following order:

```
ALTER TABLE user_profile ADD INDEX
  (city, lazy, has_avatar, inactive, gender, /* equality conditions */
   id /* range */
   challenge_count, age, /* also in range conditions, but the index won't be used */
   user_id, country_id, relationship_status_id, work_status_id, field_of_work_id,
   field_of_study_id, education_level_id, religion_id /* covering index */
);
```

That's 16 columns, the maximum for an index. If you reference other columns in your select-list, you spoil the covering-index optimization so you might as well skip all those extra columns.

I guessed that `id` would be the most selective column in a range condition, but if you think challenge_count or age would be more selective, then change the order.

You might also like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: masterfully explained

Comment: Thanks, indeed great explanation! It worked for me when using 'city', as a first field. But, when executing another query with 'country_id' (FK) instead of city, the index is not used.
Instead it uses: user_profile_d860be3c (key name of country_id),has_avatar,lazy,inactive,gender.

Comment: @jurer, when you look up someone in the phone book, it's really easy if you're looking for them by last name. But if you look for them by first name, the order of the phone book isn't so helpful. Think about why this is.